# how do promises work with #then and #json?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, react-redux, es6-promise

I'm confused on why the first example works, but the 2nd doesn't. I believe it has to do with calling json will resolve the response into javascript object? So then it returns a promise that has to be placed into a then function? I get this because of the error that is thrown in the 3rd example. What does #json do exactly?

```
export const promiseErrorMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  const url = action.url
  const fetchName = action.fetchName
  return Promise.resolve(fetch(url)).then((response) => {
    return response.json()
  }).then((data) => {
    store.dispatch({data: data, needDirection: true, fetchName: fetchName })
  })
}

//works

export const promiseErrorMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  const url = action.url
  const fetchName = action.fetchName
  return Promise.resolve(fetch(url)).then((response) => {
    store.dispatch({data: response.json(), needDirection: true, fetchName: fetchName })
  })
}

//doesn't work

export const promiseErrorMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  const url = action.url
  const fetchName = action.fetchName
  return Promise.resolve(fetch(url)).then((response) => {
    console.log(resopnse.json())
    return response.json()
  }).then((data) => {
    store.dispatch({data: data, needDirection: true, fetchName: fetchName })
  })
}

//throws error
```

Comment: `response.json()` returns a **promise**. You have a typo in your last example: `resopnse.json()`. That might be the source of the error.

Comment: What is the difference between first and third examples? What is purpose of using `Promise.resolve()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`response.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) returns a promise. You can't use the result of it immediately, you have to wait for the promise to resolve.

Also, you don't need to use `Promise.resolve()`. `fetch()` already returns a promise.

And instead of writing `{data: data}` you can just write `{data}`. This is called [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015).

Your third example throws an error, because you can't call the `json()` method twice.

Comment: _"Your third example throws an error, because you can't call the `json()` method twice"_ Ahh, the `response` is locked reading using the `.json()` method. Though are you sure the method cannot be called twice? Or,  cannot be called again during ongoing read without throwing an error?

Comment: @guest271314 You can't call `json()` second time, even if the promise from the first call has been resolved. For example, `fetch('http://httpbin.org/get').then(r => r.json().then(() => r)).then(r => r.json())` throws `Already read` on Chrome and `Body has already been consumed.` on Firefox.

Comment: You could clone the response `fetch("http://httpbin.org/get").then(r => {
  var clone = r.clone();
  r.json().then(json1 => console.log("json1", json1))
  .then(() => {
    clone.json().then(json2 => console.log("json2", json2))
  })
})`